# ImageAdjust corr parameter

Tags: image-processing

I have a problem understanding one of the possible ways to invoke ImageAdjust.

The docs state that:

> ImageAdjust[image,corr,{in_min,in_max}] first rescales so that the
>   range of input values in_min to in_max is mapped to 0 to 1.

but nowhere in there is stated what `corr` is.

Comment: It's the gamma correction $\{c, b, \gamma\}$, as in the previous function forms, but shortened to `corr`.

Comment: I thought so at first, then I did a `{ImageAdjust[img, 1, {0.4, 0.7}], ImageAdjust[img, {1, 0.4, 0.7}]}` for a test image - the results are not the same at all

Comment: I'm saying that corr is just like the second argument in `ImageAdjust[image,{c,b,gamma}]`, so that we get `ImageAdjust[image,{c,b,gamma},{min,max}]`. I don't see where you got `{1, 0.4, 0.7}` from?

Comment: ok sorry, I mixed up - now `{ImageAdjust[img, g, {0.4, 0.7}], ImageAdjust[img, {g,0,1}, {0.4, 0.7}]}` test equal, for each g value